# Как создать вертикальную полосу прокрутки в фрейме с текстом и вертикальную с горизонтальной в другом фрейме на том же экране

Tags: html, iframe, simple-html-dom

Преподаватель дал задание на создание фреймов и полос прокрутки, но абсолютно ничего не объяснил. Я перерыла уже все сайты, которые более-менее подходили мне по теме и ничего не нашла.

Помогите. Вот пример, который я сделала, все выводит, как надо, но полосы прокрутки ни в каких вариантах не появляются. Ни через scrolling, ни через style и т.д.
Нужно, чтобы в первом фрейме была полоса прокрутки справа и в четвертом фрейме - справа и снизу. Что мне нужно делать?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Фреймы</title>
</head>
<frameset cols="25%, *" >
<frame src="Fr1.htm" name="Fr1">
<frameset rows="50%, *" >
<frame src="Fr2.htm" name="Fr2">
<frameset cols="50%, *" > 
<frame src="Fr3.htm" name="Fr3">
<frame src="Fr4.htm" name="Fr4">
</frameset>
</frameset>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:
В Fr1.htm добавить

```
<html style="overflow-y:scroll;">
<!-- тут что то -->
</html>
```

в Fr4.htm добавить

```
<html style="overflow:scroll;">
<!-- тут что то -->
</html>
```

(можно через тег `<style>` но суть та же)